# Determine HTC Desire screen type

Tags: htc-desire, screen

The first HTC Desire devices used to have AMOLED screens, before HTC switched to SLCD. How can I tell whether my handset has an AMOLED or an SLCD screen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try looking at a black picture in the dark. With AMOLED the picture should be pure black. With SLCD you should see the backlight making the picture look greyish.